# Adding / Removing values from an input based on checkbox statuses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form with bunch of checkboxes. I need to add or remove CaseIDs from the input if user checks or unchecks them.

The desired result is the unique caseIDs that are checked. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// This is what I have so far :

let selectedCases = $('input[id="save-info"]').filter(':checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

let existingCases = $('#selected-cases').val();

$('#summary').html(selectedCases.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="test-form" id="test-form" action="/delMe8.cfm" method="post">

<div class="col-12">
  <label for="selected-cases" class="form-label">selected cases<span class="text-muted"> *</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="selected-cases" name="selected-cases" class="form-control" value="3966382,4168801,4168802,4169839">
</div>
<hr class="my-4">
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="3966382" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 3966382</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4029501">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4029501</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168818">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168818</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168801" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168801</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168802" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168802</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168822">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168822</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="3966388">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 3966388</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4114087">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4114087</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="3966385">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 3966385</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169838">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169838</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169843">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169843</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168829">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168829</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168828">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168828</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4168835">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4168835</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169835">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169835</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169836">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169836</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169837">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169837</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="4169839" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 4169839</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="3946200">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 3946200</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="save-info" value="3946201">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="save-info">Save CaseID : 3946201</label>
</div>


<button class="w-10 btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save</button>

<div class="col-md-5">
  <div id="summary">
    selected-cases : <br/>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Assigning the same id to multiple elements is not admissible in valid HTML. The expression  `$('input[id="save-info"]')` will only return one DOM element in the jQuery object.

Comment: IDs **must be unique**. Use classes instead.

Comment: Also FYI, you don't need to use nor `for` nor `id`. Simply wrap into label like: `<label><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3966382" checked><span>Save CaseID : 3966382</span></label>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly edited version that will work in the expected way:

```js
$("#test-form")
 .on("input",collectAllChecked)
 .submit(function(ev){ // at submit time: copy input text to #summary div
  $("#summary").html("selected-cases : <br/>"+$("#selected-cases").val())
  ev.preventDefault();
})
function collectAllChecked(ev){
  const checked=$(".form-check-input:checked").get().map(el=>el.value)
  $("#selected-cases").val(checked.join(","));
}
collectAllChecked();
```

```css
#selected-cases {width:500px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test-form">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="selected-cases" class="form-label">selected cases<span class="text-muted"> *</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="selected-cases" name="selected-cases" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <hr class="my-4"><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3966382" checked>Save CaseID : 3966382</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4029501">Save CaseID : 4029501</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168818" checked>Save CaseID : 4168818</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168801">Save CaseID : 4168801</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168802">Save CaseID : 4168802</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168822" checked>Save CaseID : 4168822</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3966388">Save CaseID : 3966388</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4114087">Save CaseID : 4114087</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3966385">Save CaseID : 3966385</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169838">Save CaseID : 4169838</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169843">Save CaseID : 4169843</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168829">Save CaseID : 4168829</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168828">Save CaseID : 4168828</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4168835">Save CaseID : 4168835</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169835">Save CaseID : 4169835</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169836">Save CaseID : 4169836</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169837">Save CaseID : 4169837</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="4169839">Save CaseID : 4169839</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3946200">Save CaseID : 3946200</label>
  </div><div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="3946201">Save CaseID : 3946201</label>
  </div>


  <button class="w-10 btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save</button>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="summary">
      selected-cases : <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I also worked in the recommendations of @RokoC.Buljan: The event function for "input" events is now a separate function that is used to calculate the initial state.

Comment: instead of `$("form").on("input",function(){` you might rather use the OP's form ID (you decided to remove) : `$("#test-form").on("input", ".form-check-input", function(){`

Comment: Thanks, @RokoC.Buljan, fixed it. I simply did not see the form ID at first.

Comment: Also, would be also nice to separate the function into its own method so that one does not necessarily need to prepopulate the *selected* with `value="3966382,4168801,4168802,4169839"` but instead, just call that function on both checkboxes "change" and on *init*.

Comment: PS: still, delegating like `$("#test-form").on("input", ".form-check-input", function(){` is way better - specially in the case when the form checkboxes might be dynamically generated.

Comment: Also, not sure if OP missed it, but the input `#selected-cases` is not attributed as `disabled` and therefore the application misses also the "other way around" logic: from input to checkboxes. Not sure if that's in the scope of this question though. Specially since in that case value validation (matching checkbox value) has to be implemented as well.

Comment: Any time something is changed in the text-input field the same event function as for the check boxes is triggered and the content is quickly restored to the correct state again.  So, setting the input to "disabled" might be the logical thing but it is not really necessary here.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann with that exact implementation, yes. Makes sense. But it's a weird UX.

Answer (score 2):

So easy with vanilla JS...

```js
const testForm = document.forms['test-form']
  ;
setSelects() // for page load INIT
  ;
testForm.addEventListener('input',setSelects) // including any checkBox click event
  ;
function setSelects()
  {
  let formInputs = Object.fromEntries( new FormData(testForm) );
  testForm['selected-cases'].value = Object.keys(formInputs).filter(k=>!isNaN(k)).join(',');
  }   //     ^-- this is element name

testForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  testForm.summary.textContent = testForm['selected-cases'].value;
  }); //     ^-- this is element name
```

```css
body {
  font-family : 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
label { 
  display : block;
  cursor  : pointer;
  } 
input[name="selected-cases"] { 
  width : 500px; 
  }
output[name="summary"] { 
  display : block; 
  }
output[name="summary"]::before {
  content : attr(name) ': \0A'
}
```

```html
<form name="test-form" action="/delMe8.cfm" method="post">

  <label>
    selected cases<sup>*</sup>
    <input type="text" name="selected-cases" value="" readonly>
  </label>
  <hr>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="3966382" value="x" checked>  Save CaseID : 3966382 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4029501" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4029501 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168818" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4168818 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168801" value="x" checked>  Save CaseID : 4168801 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168802" value="x" checked>  Save CaseID : 4168802 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168822" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4168822 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="3966388" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 3966388 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4114087" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4114087 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="3966385" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 3966385 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169838" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4169838 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169843" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4169843 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168829" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4168829 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168828" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4168828 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4168835" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4168835 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169835" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4169835 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169836" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4169836 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169837" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 4169837 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="4169839" value="x" checked>  Save CaseID : 4169839 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="3946200" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 3946200 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="3946201" value="x"        >  Save CaseID : 3946201 </label> 


  <button class="w-10 btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save</button>

  <output class="col-md-5" name="summary"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, using the `name` attribute for the checkboxes is a clever way forward. This way the whole `setSelects()` function can be written as a one liner: `testForm['selected-cases'].value = [...new FormData(testForm).keys()].filter(k=>+k).join(',');`. And, yes, jQuery is not really required here. Vanilla JavaScript does the job really well.